# Proving Orthogonality

Tags: orthonormal

I'm trying to prove orthogonality in the following case: 
$Q:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$
is a linear transformation that maps from an orthonormal basis 
$\mathcal{B}=\{\vec{b}_1,\vec{b}_2\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
to an Orthonormal basis then is Q orthogonal

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with dot products and such, but here's a geometric interpretation. If $Q$ sends an orthonormal basis to another one (in $\mathbb{R}^2$), then $Q$ has to be either a rotation matrix, or it rotates and reflects. Then the result immediately follows since any $2\times 2$ matrix with those properties it orthogonal.